# Error comparing two arrays using in_array()

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have an array that contains all the details (through a MySQL select ALL) of my friends and another array that contains all the details of ALL the people in a team. Now, I want to display all my friends in an HTML select list but I don't want my friends who are already part of the 'team' to show up in the select list.

I have tried using `in_array()` but I don't get any result. All my friends still show up in the select list despite the fact that some of them are already part of the 'team'.

This is the code:

```
<form action="tmembers.php" method="post">    
    <select multiple="true" name="members[]"  val id="member" class="">    
        <?php
        while($record5 = $stmt5->fetch()){    
            $friends[] = $record5;      //array containing details of all friends
        }
        while($record6 = $stmt6->fetch()){   
            $membersarray[] = $record6;  //array containing details of team members
        }

        foreach ($friends AS $t) {
            if (in_array($t, $membersarray)) {
               continue;            
            } 
        ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $t['id'] ; ?>">  
            <?php echo $t['surname'];?> <?php echo $t['firstname'] ; ?>  
        </option>

        <?php } 
        ?>

        </select>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Invite" name="invite" class=""/>
   </form>
```

Comment: If the members and friends come from database, why not use ONE sql statement does all the selection logic?

Comment: What should the query look like?

Comment: how should i know without knowing what your data looks like. It could be as easy as `SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE is_member = 0` for all i know. how good are your SQL skills?

Comment: Not too good. You know we trying to display friends that are not in the team table.  This gets the details of the team: '$team = "SELECT i.*, m.* FROM tmembers i JOIN members m ON m.id = i.members WHERE team_id = :id";' While this gets the details of my friends: '$sql5 = "SELECT i.*, m.* FROM addclique i JOIN members m ON m.id = i.clique_id WHERE adder_id = :id";'

Comment: Add to the second query left join on tmembers and in where clause team_id IS null. Try it and if you don't manage let me know

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($friends);$i++) {
    if (in_array($friends[$i], $membersarray)) {
       continue;            
    } 
}
```

Comment: `for($i=0;$i<count($friends);$i++) {` is identical to `foreach($friends as $i => $t) {` but the latter looks better :)

Comment: I did as you said and try to display the friends in the select list but all friends still showed despite that some friends are in the team table. echo "<option value='{}'>{$friends[$i]['surname']}</option>";

Answer (score 0):

```
$arraysAreEqual = ($a == $b); // TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.
$arraysAreEqual = ($a === $b); // TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.
```

See [Array Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php).

The inequality operator is `!=` while the non-identity operator is `!==` to match the equality 
operator `==` and the identity operator `===`.